# DOM element mysteriously disappears after being accessed inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html

So, I've got a function pushSession that effectively sets up a serial connection on a given comm port. If there are no valid connections, the function "getCorrectDevice" rejects its promise and jumps to .catch().

Heres the function itself-

```
function pushSession(){
    grabValidDevices()
    .then(checkDeviceSupport)
    .then(getCorrectDevice)
    .then(insertSessionHTML)
    .then(connectPort)
    .catch(function(error){
        var flag = document.getElementById("error-flag")
        var errorContainer = document.getElementById("error-container")
        application.flags.push(error)
        flag.style.backgroundColor = "white"

        var count = 0
        //errorContainer.textContent = application.flags[count]
        count++

        setTimeout(function(errors){
            var flag = document.getElementById("error-flag")
            var errorContainer = document.getElementById("error-container")
            errorContainer.textContent = ""
            console.log("showing flag")
            flag.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"
            errors.flags = [] // once an error has been push to the UI, we can reset our flags
        }, 5000, application)    
    })
}
```

When this code is executed, the element "flag" retrieved in `.catch()` at the end simply disappears- poof!- from my DOM.

After observing this behaviour for some time, It looks to me like the act of changing a style on the elements somehow causes the element to be removed from the DOM.

Immediately after calling the function `pushSession()` (specifically at the line : `flag.style.backgroundColor = "white"`), the element disappears never to be seen again. What's truly odd here is that the element background does in fact become white, and then transparent again after five seconds have passed inside `setTimeout`. This results in errors telling me the variable flag is undefined (since the DOM element no longer exists).

I can understand problems with scope, but this doesn't seem related to that at all. As I've already said, the element simply ceases to exist within the DOM.

Nothing is being passed in from a previous `.then()` call, so I'm also lead to believe this has nothing to do with my promises or their return values.

It has occurred to me that my promise will return before having the `setTimeout` callback has executed, but this shouldn't have any effect on the callbacks execution, and I definitely can't see any reason for the DOM element to simply be removed!

Is there any explanation for this behavior?

The only obvious solution I see here is to simply add the element back in dynamically with append child, but this seems hackish and unnecessary.

Comment: Is the `error-flag` by any chance a child of the `error-container` element?

Comment: Yes it is! It's the only child element inside error-container.

Comment: Well you set the text content of the element so it will remove its children... You say that flag is a child of errorContainer so, you delete the element.

Comment: I was not aware of that behavior. That that would explain the issues. I supposed that would mean I'll have reinsert the flag element dynamically.

Comment: @Carl instead of reinserting the flag element, you should think over your DOM structure.

Comment: Or don't remove it in the first place. (If you need to hide it, you can set its visibility to hidden or display:none, rather than removing it from the dom altogether)

Comment: I think what I'll do is to simply have another element over the top of error container that actually holds the error message. This means I don't have to use errorContainer.textContent and I can avoid all of these problems, it'll also allow me to preserve the formatting that's already in place.

Comment: @DanielBeck this was my original approach, the issue is that setting the textContent property of errorContainer removes its children from the DOM (including my flag icon).

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Use a different element for your text, sibling to the flag element, and set its textContent instead of the container's, so you don't destroy the flag element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So yeah, as said in the comments, and as I kinda guessed: since `error-flag` is the child of the `error-container`, and you clean out `error-container` with `errorContainer.textContent = ""`, the flag will be gone from the DOM. :)

Comment: I'll give that a shot!